# ¿Problema con checkbox y datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, checkbox

tengo un problema, lo que deseo que es mediante un ajax pueda obtener un numero de valores y hacer un recorrido en mi datatable que tiene una columna de checkbox, y si el valor de ese checkbox es igual al valor de traido por ajax que se ponga en checked:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Guias/ListaEquiposGuia",
    type: "GET",
    data: { TipGuia: TipGuia, CodGuia: CodGuia },
    success: function (data) {
        var E = JSON.parse(data)
 //var table = $('#table').datatable();
        table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        $.each(E, function (i, item) {
            if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').val() == item.CodEquipo)
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
            });
        });
    }
})
```

pordrian decirme en que me estoy equivocando, el ajax me trae una lista de valores.

Comment: Que no deberia ser: `if ($(this).val() == item.CodEquipo)`

Comment: es que el $(this).val() en la segunda parte lo toma como vacio por que antes de ese esta un $.each(E, function (i, item) { del cual no toma nada y sale de resultado asi string<anonymus> e igual cambiando de posicion el  table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () { por el  $.each(E, function (i, item) {

Answer (score 1):

bueno al final la respuesta es que el each no me estaba recorriendo el array del JSON y lo cambie por POST bueno POst y GET es lo de menos la diferencia es que en GET tienes que convertirlo a obj con JSON.parse pero en POST ya viene como objeto bueno esta fue mi solucion.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Guias/ListaEquiposGuia",
    type: "POST",
    data: { TipGuia: TipGuia, CodGuia: CodGuia },
    success: function (data) {

        for (var i in data) {
            table.$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == data[i]) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```